# How can I use the definition of convergence to prove that if $\lim(a_n)=A$ and $\lim(b_n)=B$ such that $\lim(b_n-a_n)=0$ then $A=B$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=A$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=B$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{(b_n-a_n)}=0$ then $A=B$.

This is a bit more on the theoretical side, which I struggle with. My initial thought is to write out a couple limit definitions and perhaps use the triangle inequality, but I'm kind of stumped on where to start. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)=B-A$ and leverage the uniqueness of the limit of a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Use $$|(a_n-b_n)-(A-B)|=|(a_n-A)-(b_n-B)|\le |a_n-A|+|b_n-B| $$ to prove $$\lim (a_n-b_n)=A-B$$

On the other hand  $$\lim (a_n-b_n)=0$$

Thus $$A-B=0$$ which implies $$A=B$$